# bash script to find pattern in text file and return entire line

Tags: linux, bash, file, shell, search

I need to make a bash script which loops through a bunch of .txt files in a directory, then searches each .txt for a string, and returns the entire line that string appears on

I know how to look through all the .txt files in the directory,

I just need to be pointed in the right direction for searching the file itself, and returning a line based on a match in that line

Answer (score 12):

Within one dir

```
grep "search string" *.txt
```

Search or go to sub-dir

```
find /full/path/to/dir -name "*.txt" -exec grep "search string" {} ;\
```

Comment: `\;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a loop:

`for i in $(find|grep .txt); do grep "search" "$i";`
If you also want to print the filename with each match, add `-H` to grep

Answer (score 0):

One slight addition. Add `-n` to return the line.

```
      grep -rn "foo" *.txt
```

See `grep --help` for more.